# Drop-down menu options assigned but not visible?

Tags: html, spring, drop-down-menu, frontend

I can't really understand what I'm doing wrong..
I have a drop-down menu and I want to iterate over a list of elements.
The list is read correctly and when I run the application I can even see the right options for the menu listed using "Inspect Element" from Firefox Browser...but why can't I access the selection rectangle? And it doesn't show anything. When I click on it, it's not possible to choose anything.

this is the code for the selection in the jsp:

```
<form:select path="list" class="selectpicker" multiple="true" data-max-options="4">
               <form:options items="${av_list}"/>
</form:select>
```

Where list is the object that has to be "filled" with the selection.
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your `select` is hidden (`width:.5px; opacity:0;`) presumably by bootstrap-select. Investigate why `.dropdown-menu` is greyed-out and wether it has any children.

Comment: How can I investigate it? I mean, do I have to modify the css file?

Comment: Inspect it (click on it in the inspector). Why is it greyed out? Expand the element it in the inspector. Does it have the child elements you expect? I'm not familiar with bootstrap but it looks to me like this custom dropdown menu is in some kind of 'disabled' state. Also, consider adding the 'bootstrap' tag to your question. I bet the devs with bootstrap experience will recognise the issue.

Comment: Does the template literal need to be surrounded by backticks instead of quotes?

Comment: @RobMoll it was exactly that! Do you want to post it as an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: Will do. Thanks for offering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form:options items="${av_list}"/>
```

The template literal should be surrounded by backticks instead of quotes. Like this:

```
<form:options items=`${av_list}`/>
```

I wish I could tell you exactly why that causes the symptom you were seeing, but I cannot. Maybe someone brighter than me can comment regarding that.